# Kali Linux 2020 Brightness Issue

Tags: linux, brightness

When I try to decrease brightness means it won't change. I have seen some videos in youtube channel and try to install 'apt-get install xblacklight' this command showing an error that 'E: Unable to locate package xblacklight'.
Please someone help to clear this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your backlight won't change when you try to slide the brightness slider, there is likely a driver issue.

Try opening Driver Manager on Kali, and then choose a different driver for your GPU.

The same issue happened to me with an Nvidia GPU. It fixed the problem.

However, if that is not an option for you, as a last resort, try:
`xrandr --output [monitor] --brightness [brightness level on a scale of 0-1]`

If you don't know how you monitor should be addressed, you can use the command
 `xrandr --listactivemonitors` to list all the possible monitors.

The last resort won't save any battery, but at least it will save your eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Add another user to your kali weekly, week number 33. The administrator can't seem to adjust screen brightness, but the lower privileged desktop user can; this is what I discovered after I installed this distro on the bare metal.

In terminal, do this:

1. get root access, type: sudo su
2. type command: sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
3. answer y to the question you see on screen, this will install to proceed.
4. when install is completed, type command: exit
5. then again, type command: exit
6. in your drop down menu go to settings
7. you will find 2 new entries, Time and Date, & Users and Groups.

Click on, Users and Groups, to add a lower privileged desktop user on your system. The desktop user will have the ability to adjust screen brightness, the administrator won't; this is what I have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the brightness level in the Kali Linux terminal using brightnessctl package. First, you may have to install the package using the following command

```
 sudo apt-get install brightnessctl
```

After installation, you can increase the brightness using,

```
brightnessctl -q s +10%
```

And decrease the brightness using the below command.

```
brightnessctl -q s 10%-
```

Answer (score 0):

for those of you who wonder how to increase the screen brightness of your kali box: I was just wondering that. So instead of begging the gurus for help I turned to google and found the command xrandr. I thought there should be a GUI method but since this is a hacker OS that must be the way it is. Then after about a half hour for some strange reason (could it have been GOD) I clicked the battery icon and found the GUI method.

--edit--

forgot to mention the caveat: I'm running Kali live with persistence.